# All steps required to produce a XML file from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

[image][image][image][image]I need to produce output in specified XML format, thought it would be easy in 2021,  tried first to convert it into XSD using [online](https://extendsclass.com/xml-schema-validator.html) services and use it with my SQL (using `CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION Schema1 AS @Schema1`);but this didn't work, I suspect that there is no easy way to generate XML using XSD, still need to work with your `SELECT`, please correct me if I'm wrong. My example below is not final. I'm using SQL Server 2017 and have only SSMS as my tool. (no .NET available).

picxxx[image: xxx]

Here is my sample XML.
[image]

ryba[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Users>
    <User Active="0"  gender="Male" DOB="1965-02-12" mi="X" lName="John" fName="Dorx">
        <CInfo ResArea="Montigo"/>
        <Demographic race="Asian" HE="No"/>
        <RA>
            <Memb StartDD="2004-06-11" eStatus="Active" StatusAsOf="2004-05-12" UserID="XHD15"/>
        </RA>
    </User>
    <User Active="0"  gender="Male" DOB="1977-04-14"  mi="X" lName="Mario" fName="Ma">
        <CInfo ResArea="Blanco"/>
        <Demographic race="White" HE="Yes"/>
        <RA>
            <Memb StartDD="2004-02-22" eStatus="Active" StatusAsOf="2004-03-26" UserID="MMX12"/>
            <Memb StartDD="2004-12-22" eStatus="Active" StatusAsOf="2004-05-26" UserID="MMX12"/>
        </RA>
    </User>
</Users>
```

And here is my test code and SQL (which is not final yet, I still struggling with formatting all tags, and I probably need to do subquery and grouping to list 2 `Memb` under same `User`).

```
/*
SELECT * INTO #t FROM (
SELECT 'XHD15' UserID, '1965-02-12' DOB, 'John' lName,  'Dorx' fName, 'x' mi,  'Montigo' ResArea,  '2004-06-11' StartDD, 'Active' eStatus, '2004-05-12' StatusAsOf, 'Asian' race, 'No' HE  union
SELECT 'MMX12' UserID, '1977-04-14' DOB, 'Mario' lName,  'Ma' fName, 'x' mi, 'Blanco' ResArea,  '2004-02-22' StartDD, 'Active' eStatus, '2004-03-26' StatusAsOf, 'White' race, 'No' HE  union
SELECT 'MMX12' UserID, '1977-04-14' DOB, 'Mario' lName,  'Ma' fName, 'x' mi, 'Blanco' ResArea,  '2004-12-22' StartDD, 'Active' eStatus, '2004-12-26' StatusAsOf, 'White' race, 'No' HE  )x  
*/
  SELECT  Lname AS [@Lname], Fname [@Fname], mi [@mi],  DOB [@DOB],
         MAX(ResArea) AS [CInfo/@ResArea],
         MAX(race) AS [Demographic/@race],    MAX(HE) AS [Demographic/@HE] 
       , MAX(StartDD) AS [RA/Memb/@StartDD],  MAX(eStatus) AS [RA/Memb/@eStatus],   MAX(StatusAsOf)  AS [RA/Memb/@StatusAsOf]
       -- Need subquery for multi StartDD
 FROM #t AS [User]    
 GROUP BY Lname, Fname , mi ,  DOB 
      FOR XML PATH ('User'),  ROOT ('Users')-- , ELEMENTS
```

[image]
[image: bravo]

[image]

[image]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

The SQL below is using two aliases: **p**(arent) and **c**(hild).

When generating nested XML, parent and child data sets are joined via `WHERE` clause.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    UserID CHAR(5), DOB DATE, 
    lName VARCHAR(20), 
    fName VARCHAR(20), 
    mi VARCHAR(20),
    ResArea VARCHAR(30),
    StartDD DATE,
    eStatus VARCHAR(10),
    StatusAsOf DATE,
    race  VARCHAR(20),
    HE VARCHAR(5)
);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('XHD15', '1965-02-12', 'John' ,  'Dorx', 'x', 'Montigo', '2004-06-11', 'Active', '2004-05-12', 'Asian', 'No'),
('MMX12', '1977-04-14', 'Mario',  'Ma'  , 'x', 'Blanco' , '2004-02-22', 'Active', '2004-03-26', 'White', 'No'),
('MMX12', '1977-04-14', 'Mario',  'Ma'  , 'x', 'Blanco' , '2004-12-22', 'Active', '2004-12-26', 'White', 'No');
 -- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT Lname AS [@Lname], Fname [@Fname], mi [@mi],  DOB [@DOB]
    , ResArea AS [CInfo/@ResArea]
    , race AS [Demographic/@race], HE AS [Demographic/@HE]
    , (SELECT StartDD AS [@StartDD]
            , eStatus AS [@eStatus]
            , StatusAsOf AS [@StatusAsOf]
            , UserID AS [@UserID]
        FROM @tbl AS c
        WHERE p.UserID = c.UserID
        FOR XML PATH('Memb'), TYPE, ROOT('RA')
    )
FROM @tbl AS p
GROUP BY p.UserID, p.Lname, p.Fname, p.mi, p.DOB, p.ResArea, p.race, p.HE
FOR XML PATH ('User'), TYPE, ROOT ('Users');
```

**Output XML**

```
<Users>
  <User Lname="Mario" Fname="Ma" mi="x" DOB="1977-04-14">
    <CInfo ResArea="Blanco" />
    <Demographic race="White" HE="No" />
    <RA>
      <Memb StartDD="2004-02-22" eStatus="Active" StatusAsOf="2004-03-26" UserID="MMX12" />
      <Memb StartDD="2004-12-22" eStatus="Active" StatusAsOf="2004-12-26" UserID="MMX12" />
    </RA>
  </User>
  <User Lname="John" Fname="Dorx" mi="x" DOB="1965-02-12">
    <CInfo ResArea="Montigo" />
    <Demographic race="Asian" HE="No" />
    <RA>
      <Memb StartDD="2004-06-11" eStatus="Active" StatusAsOf="2004-05-12" UserID="XHD15" />
    </RA>
  </User>
</Users>
```